# Vista Address Book Gadget--Can you copy to another Vista computer?

Tags: windows-vista, contacts, address-book, desktop-gadget

I have a Vista 64-bit desktop and want to copy the Address book gadget, which includes all my Outlook contact information, to my Vista laptop, which does not have Outlook (due to Microsoft install limitations).  I tried copying the WAB files to the laptop, but this does not seem to activate and populate the Address Book gadget.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

WAB files are not used for Outlook, Outlook saves contacts in *.pst files. The Address Book gadget reads this *.pst file to present you contacts, and it doesn't maintain its own list.

In other words, copying the gadget won't copy contacts to the new computer. Besides, it won't even show any contacts if you don't install Outlook on the new computer, and copy your addresses to it.